# Get line and column number of items from a json file

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I am creating a typescript library to validate a JSON file against some custom constraints, for example I have this json file:

```
[
  {
    "nodes": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "node 1"
      },
      {
        "id": 1, // <--- here needs to throw an error because of duplicate ids
        "name": "node 2"
      }
    ],

    "edges": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "nodeId": 1,
        "name": "edge 1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "nodeId": 3, // <--- here needs to throw an error because of node id does not exist
        "name": "edge 1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am already using `json shcema` to validate against the structure of the json (like `required` properties, types...).

Using typescript I can easily loop throw the 2 lists and find the errors but the problem is that i can't get the location of that error (`line` & `column`) so is there a way to get line numbers for my errors? and if it is not possible then is there another way to return a useful error for the users?

Comment: The [API of node-jsonc-parser](https://github.com/microsoft/node-jsonc-parser#api) looks pretty promising. Alternatively [json-to-ast](https://github.com/vtrushin/json-to-ast) might work, but then you would have to process the AST output which is probably rather cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

Line and column numbers would be very complicated, you'll have to roll out your own JSON parser for that, because the stock `JSON.parse` doesn't retain this information.

A more realistic option would be maintain a stack of keys while validating and give the user something like "Error xyz at nodes -> item 5 -> someKey". Example:

```js
json = {
    foo: [
        1,
        2,
        {
            bar: {
                baz: 'error!'
            }
        }
    ]
}

function validate(obj, stack = []) {
    if (Array.isArray(obj))
        obj.forEach((v, n) => validate(v, stack.concat('index ' + n)))
    else if (typeof obj === 'object')
        Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v]) => validate(v, stack.concat(k)))
    else if (obj === 'error!')
        console.log('ERROR at ' + stack.join(' -> '))
}

validate(json)
```

Comment: okk so it is up to the user to search for the error message inside of the json file right? also  when i was searching i came across AST (abstract syntax tree) which tokenize the json file and it gives the location of each item but the travers of the generated tree is complicated, and also i don't know if this would scale on bigger json files... so your solution seems to solve the problem but just want to be sure does the AST is a good idea or not?

Comment: In the long run, AST is better and definitely more user-friendly, but as I said, you need to program your own json parser for that.